# Change default localized error message of DocumentViewer

Tags: c#, .net

`DocumentViewer` WPF contorol is using `System.Windows.SR.Get(string)` internal method to get messages displayed to user durning search. Even though I have `pl-PL` set as `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture`, those are not localized.

I've investigated a little and `System.Windows.SR.Get(string)` uses `new ResourceManager("ExceptionStringTable", typeof (System.Windows.SR).Assembly)` from `PresentationFramework` assembly which in turn loads ExceptionStringTable.resources file with those messages. From what I understand this is standard localization technique across the Framework.

My question is: How can I make WPF to display my custom localized messages? I've tried using hacky reflection and was able to access inner `ResourceManager` of `SR` class. Should I wrap it in my custom `ResourceManager` implementation, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to go with reflection hack. You have to use this code in application startup to swap `ResourceDictionary` used in internal .NET class `SR`:

```
var assembly = typeof(DocumentViewer).Assembly;
var sr = assembly.GetType("System.Windows.SR");

var field = sr.GetField("_resourceManager", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);


var resourceManager = (ResourceManager)field.GetValue(null);
var wrapper = new ResourceManagerWrapper(resourceManager);


wrapper.SetString("DocumentViewerSearchUpCompleteLabel", "test");
wrapper.SetString("DocumentViewerSearchDownCompleteLabel", "test");
wrapper.SetString("DocumentViewerSearchCompleteTitle", "test");
//And so on... you can find all those messages with dotPeek or similar tool in `DocumentViewer` implementation

field.SetValue(null, wrapper);
```

My wrapper class which forwards resource lookup to ResourceManager is quite simple:

```
public class ResourceManagerWrapper : ResourceManager
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> local_ = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    private ResourceManager manager_;
    public ResourceManagerWrapper(ResourceManager manager)
    {
        this.manager_ = manager;
    }

    public override string GetString(string name)
    {
        string value;
        if(local_.TryGetValue(name, out value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            return manager_.GetString(name);
        }
    }

    public void SetString(string key, string value)
    {
        local_[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've searched a lot for same fix, very annoying issues with DocumentViewer. Thanks for this,your solution works.